# How to switch data between two columns with a condition?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have collected several different datasets and formatted them into one and it looks something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(database = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
                         longitude = c(45,45,45,11,11,11,43,43,43),
                         latitude = c(12,12,12,42,42,42,12,12,12),
                         interval = c(0,2,2,2,0,4,0,2,3))
```

I noticed that from one of the datasets longitude and latitude are switched around. So for `database==B` I want to switch the values between the `longitude` and `latitude` columns. So it ends up like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(database = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
                         longitude = c(45,45,45,42,42,42,43,43,43),
                         latitude = c(12,12,12,11,11,11,12,12,12),
                         interval = c(0,2,2,2,0,4,0,2,3))
```

Comment: Using the dplyr package, try:

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(longitude2 = case_when(longitude < mean(longitude) ~ latitude,
                                TRUE ~ longitude),
         latitude2 = case_when(latitude > mean(latitude) ~ longitude,
                               TRUE ~ latitude))

This works for at least the example sample you have provided.